# What is the relevant ISO or similar standard to refer to for painted metal corrosion testing?

Tags: materials

We have an electronic display product that will be installed in a street side application. The front part is made from metal and exposed to the elements so it will need to be painted to protect it from corrosion.

Does anyone know what would be a good international standard to refer to when specifying the corrosion resistance of the paint and the final products?

Answer (score 4):

> what would be a good international standard to refer to

I claim to be no expert in international (or even American) standards, but a quick search on my company's database gives me some options that may be worth considering.

> The front part is exposed to the elements so it will need to be painted to protect it from corrosion.

I assume you mean that the housing will be steel since you are concerned about corrosion.  Consider having a look at the following standards:

- ISO 12944-5, *Paints and varnishes — Corrosion protection of steel structures by protective paint systems — Part 5: Protective paint systems - Second Edition*
- ASTM D1014, *Standard Practice for Conducting Exterior Exposure Tests of Paints and Coatings on Metal Substrates*
- ASTM MNL20, *Corrosion Tests and Standards: Application and Interpretation - 2nd Edition*

> specifying the corrosion resistance of the paint and the final products?

You mention paint, but a galvanized coating may be fitting for your application as well.

- ISO 1461, *Hot dip galvanized coatings on fabricated iron and steel articles - Specifications and test methods - Third Edition*
- ASTM A123, *Standard Specification for Zinc (Hot-Dip Galvanized) Coatings on Iron and Steel Products*